# How do I play an HTTP music stream over SSH?

Tags: ssh, http, mplayer, streaming, music

I know I can just do `mplayer <stream>` to *open* and *play* a stream on the local machine. However, I'm behind a firewall.

Instead, I'd like to *open* the stream on a *remote machine*, but still *play* it on *this one*. Remote connections are what [SSH](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) is for, but doing `ssh "mplayer <stream>"` both opens *and* plays the stream on the remote.

SSH's `-x` flag enables X11 display forwarding. Do I need that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `ssh`'s `-L` flag to create a tunnel from your system to a remote:

```
ssh -L <localport>:<streamhost>:<streamport> <user>@<remote>
```

You can then connect to your end of the tunnel with `mplayer` as you would otherwise:

```
mplayer localhost:<localport>
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if the HTTP server is using virtual domains (or in other words, requires a proper domain name sent by the client as an HTTP header). To solve this problem, you can for example temporarily add a rule to your `hosts` file that will make `mplayer` think that the target domain is hosted at local machine.

Comment: Or you could use `-http-header-fields` to force a `Host` header.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you mind clarifying where?  I don't such an option in `man ssh`.

Comment: @LiamWilliam: It's a `mplayer` option.

Answer (score 34):

You can use `wget` over `ssh` to open an HTTP connection and output stream data, then `mplayer` on the local machine to play it.

```
ssh <user>@<host> "wget <stream> -O -" | mplayer -cache 512 -
```

The subtleties:

- `wget`'s `-O` (capital letter oh) option sets its output file; `-` (dash) implies `stdout`.
- `mplayer`'s `-cache` option causes a configurable amount of input to be buffered, compensating for network jitter. The `-` (dash) option makes it read from `stdin`.

Try streaming [SceneSat Radio](http://scenesat.com/), for example. `http://r1.scenesat.com:8000/scenesat`

Comment: I don't even know what kind of music this is, but because I'm piping it, it's awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Note that the question doesn't mention any particular protocol over which music is streamed. There are other protocols over which music can be streamed, for example RTP and MMS. Both can be played by `mplayer`, but not downloaded by `wget`.

Comment: @liori Good point. This clearly isn't a general solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can set up a [SOCKS proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS):

```
ssh -D localhost:8080 user@remotehost
mplayer http_proxy://localhost:8080/http://stream
```

You can use tell any other application, such as your web browser, to use this proxy too.

Comment: Does the http_proxy feature actually work with SOCKS proxies too? The feature is undocumented in my man page, and various sites on the web prefer the `tsocks` approach.

Comment: @liori: Yes, this works together with `tsocks mplayer -playlist http://bassdrive.com/bassdrive.m3u`. Thanks for your advise. Without tsocks (aka only with `http_proxy://…`) it didn’t work.

Answer (score 6):

`sshfs` is a wonderful tool for cases like this. It hides many a firewall and allows you to use whatever player you choose (though mplayer is still a nice choice).

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs # your favorite packager here
sshfs me@mydomain.org:/home/arthur/Music ~/Music
```

I also run [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) listening to port 4040 on `localhost` and then `ssh`-tunnel home with

```
ssh -L 4040:localhost:4040 me@mydomain.com
```

I can then open Subsonic in the browser at `http://localhost:4040`.